# Spark container failed. Shall I trust the results I got?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I have a quite long Spark job only consisting of a map operation.
I tried to launch it several times with different number of partitions, executors, and the maximum amount of memory I could give (16G + 2G of overhead).
During my last attempt few executors were killed because of memory overheads, however, the output was produced and it seems ok (obviously, I couldn't check all the rows of my dataframe, though). 
Moreover, I found a _SUCCESS file in the output directory.

Shall I trust the output I got?

Answer (score 0):

I think output will be correct because you have _SUCCESS file and also if some of you executor dies because of out of memory spark is fault tolerant so the work load will be transfer to the other executor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Sandeep. Do you know if there is any documentation covering this case?